# How to pass an uiimage to another view controller?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

How to pass the `uiimage` selected in `uiimagepickercontroller` in MainViewController to SecondViewController? It did push to the SecondViewController, however the `uiimage` is empty.

I've searched through the web, tried with the solutions but still cannot get it work.

`photoImage` is the `uiimageview` I've declared in SecondViewController.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
   [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [secondVC.photoImage setImage:[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    [secondVC release];
}
```

Comment: Isn't the `[secondVC release]` the problem, since you release it just after pushing it onto the navigation controller's stack?

Comment: it is the same even if I've removed `[secondVC release];`, can't figure out the problem really

Comment: What does the property declaration of `photoImage` look like?  What do you get if you put `NSLog(@"Image: %@", [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"]);` just before calling `setImage:`?

Comment: @psycho this is not the case, by pushing the viewController onto the navigation stack the navigationController takes a retain to it and therefore it is safe and required to `release`

Comment: @zeropt7 do the checks that @phillip Mills mentioned and also take note you should be using the constant `UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage` and not using the string `@"UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"`. They have the same value but Apple may decide to change this at a later date. Using the constant will also ensure that the compiler checks the spelling of the constant to save issues with typos in the string

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for your help. The property declaration is: `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *photoImage;` and this is what I got in output after I've put your `NSLog` code `Image: <UIImage: 0xc092e40>`

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks, I'm used to work with MonoTouch (C#), so my knowledge about objective C is kinda insignifiant. 
@zeropt7 Another idea, though, is `allowsEditing` true in your `UIImagePickerController`? It's default state is false, and I remember reading somewhere `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]` may be null in this case, so you must use `[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]`. I don't know if this behaviour is the same in objective C?

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared class that will store the image, and access it wherever you want.

In MainViewController assign that image in that shared class' ivar, and in SecondViewController access it.

Edit :

Below code shows how to implement shared class, this may not be syntactically correct, because currently I am not using mac, so I cant complile.

```
@interface SomeManager : NSObject
    +(id)myImage;
@end

@implementation SomeManager
    +(id)myImage{    
        static id myImage= nil; 
        @synchronized([self class]){ 
            if (myImage== nil) { 
                myImage= //put your image here; 
            } 
        }
        return myImage;
    }
 @end
```

Comment: Do you have some codes or tutorial links that can point me to the right direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @zeropt7 — dont do this. your original approach is the right one.

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImageView` in your second view controller doesn't exist until the `viewDidLoad` method of that controller is called.  Put a property into `SecondViewController` that holds a `UIImage`, store the reference to the image you want to use in it when you push the view controller (instead of trying to set the image view), and then move your `setImage:` call into the second view controller's `viewDidLoad``.